# How to parse time like this '\/Date(-62135596800000)\/' with Python

Tags: python, datetime, time

How do I parse a time like this '/Date(-62135596800000)/' with Python?

I searched the internet, but was unable to find a solution.

Link:http://211.137.19.74:8089/Ajax/GetStationDetailList?cityName=%E6%B2%88%E9%98%B3

TimePoint:"/Date(-62135596800000)/"
and the time should be 2016:12:31: 01:00

Comment: What date is that number supposed to represent? Probably not "62 trillion seconds before the Unix epoch", I'm guessing.

Comment: @Kevin... that would be normal for paleontologists!

Comment: Can you give us some context on where this date string came from?

Comment: @tdelaney added some detail

Comment: @Kevin I've added some detail

Comment: It's an ASP.NET JSON Date (old-style), and that value is equivalent to `0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`  (Which is `DateTime.MinValue` in UTC in .NET).  The number is *milliseconds* since the Unix epoch.

Comment: Are you certain that the string  you've given `Date(-62135596800000)` actually equates to 2016:12:31: 01:00? What would be the number for 2016:12:31: 02:00?

Comment: @BryanOakley  you can check the home page here. The datetime shows in the right up corner . http://211.137.19.74:8089/

Comment: @MattJohnson So the time isn't the right time?

Comment: That's right.  All values in your API responses are set to the default date of `0001-01-01 00:00:00.000 UTC`.  For whatever reason, the server is not sending any current dates on that field.

Comment: @MattJohnson Got it. Though I didn't know what's the meaning of this time format. But It remains the same and nothing changed. So I have to find another way to get the current date. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

`/Date(N)/` is usually the format for dates serialized by the built-in WCF JSON serializer in .NET. The value can then be reconstructed by calling `new Date(N)` in JavaScript.

Running that in JavaScript will show why this date is very likely just wrong:

```
new Date(-62135596800000)
// Date 0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

As you can see, you get the `0001-01-01 00:00:00.00`. This also happens to be the *default* value in .NET for empty `DateTime` objects:

```csharp
default(DateTime).ToString("u") // 0001-01-01 00:00:00Z
new DateTime(0).ToString("u") // 0001-01-01 00:00:00Z
```

So, sorry to say it like that, but that server is just broken.

---

That all being said, once you get a valid date, you can parse the number in Python using [`datetime.fromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) or [`datetime.utcfromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(1483120713887 // 1000)
datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 30, 18, 58, 33)
```

Comment: Negative numbers are indeed valid, and you just showed an example of that.

Comment: @MattJohnson Nevermind, I was wrong. Sorry about that.

Comment: Sure, no problem. :)

Comment: Wouldn't `datetime.utcfromtimestamp` be more appropriate?

Comment: @poke Great. I deleted mine.

Answer (score 1):

Using python 3.x
Looks like epoch time (in nano seconds starting January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT). You could use something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(62135596800000 // 1000000000)
print(dt)
```

As for the value you're getting, you can't have a negative epoch time stamp (-62135596800000 would be invalid). If the - indicates negative, it might be another time stamp format.

Comment: Milliseconds, not nanoseconds, and yes - you absolutely can have a negative epoch timestamp.  The unix epoch is `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`.  You'll get negatives in 1969 and earlier.

Comment: @MattJohnson Oh sorry, I didn't realize that. The datetime.fromtimestamp function throws an error when I used the negative value. Turns out python restricts the date range by default for some reason. "It’s common for this to be restricted to years in 1970 through 2038" - from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

Comment: Interesting... And [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17231712/634824) is a solution to that.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Source**: [ASP.NET FORUMS](https://forums.asp.net/post/6054965.aspx)

```
var dateString = "/Date(1526409000000)/".substr(6);
var currentTime = new Date(parseInt(dateString));
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var day = currentTime.getDate();
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
var date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
alert(date);
```